# 32-bit Ubuntu VM Image for M1 Mac running UTM?

Tags: 14.04, 32-bit, macbook-pro

I'm looking for an 32-bit Ubuntu VM image which I can run on my M1 Mac using UTM. I've done some scrimmaging online but have come up empty on my efforts. Does anyone know of any VM images that are available for download that are 32 bit, ubuntu distribution images which can run on Mac's M1?

Ideally, I'd have liked something like this image: https://seedsecuritylabs.org/labsetup.html which is built on Ubuntu 16.04. However, any 32 bit Ubuntu image that works on M1 would work!

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a *supported* release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in *extended* support and supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *The ISO you mention is not a Ubuntu product thus off-topic here, as would questions asking for non-Ubuntu (Ubuntu based) systems; please read the on-topic for this site   All on-topic systems are downloaded from ubuntu.com which include official flavors of Ubuntu*

Comment: Ubuntu ceased creating 32-bit Desktop images several years ago due to too few volunteer testers and contributors. Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 is available in 32-bit, but will reach End Of Community Support in April 2023 (8 months). The recommended method of installing an Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server VM on MacOS is to use Multipass.